# Kubernetes Pod memory keeps on increasing and shoots way beyond Java application consumption

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, memory

**Current Setup:**

1. Java application running as Kubernetes workload on Google Kubernetes engine
2. JVM args : "-XX:+UseContainerSupport", "-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail", "-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError", "-XX:HeapDumpPath=/dumps/oom.bin", "-Xmx300m", "-Xms300m"
3. Docker memory set using deployment.yml

   limits:
   cpu: 350m
   memory: 700Mi
   requests:
   cpu: 200m
   memory: 128Mi
4. Native memory committed is below 550m when the pod is very near to hitting the max container limit. This leads me to believe that there is something apart from native memory causing this issue

   Total: reserved=1788920KB, committed=546092KB
   -                 Java Heap (reserved=307200KB, committed=307200KB)
   (mmap: reserved=307200KB, committed=307200KB)

   ```
   -                     Class (reserved=1116111KB, committed=75431KB)
                               (classes #12048)
                               (malloc=1999KB #25934) 
                               (mmap: reserved=1114112KB, committed=73432KB) 

   -                    Thread (reserved=46444KB, committed=46444KB)
                               (thread #46)
                               (stack: reserved=46240KB, committed=46240KB)
                               (malloc=153KB #270) 
                               (arena=51KB #88)

   -                      Code (reserved=259362KB, committed=57214KB)
                               (malloc=9762KB #14451) 
                               (mmap: reserved=249600KB, committed=47452KB) 

   -                        GC (reserved=1034KB, committed=1034KB)
                               (malloc=26KB #180) 
                               (mmap: reserved=1008KB, committed=1008KB) 

   -                  Compiler (reserved=321KB, committed=321KB)
                               (malloc=189KB #982) 
                               (arena=133KB #5)

   -                  Internal (reserved=39461KB, committed=39461KB)
                               (malloc=39429KB #16005) 
                               (mmap: reserved=32KB, committed=32KB) 

   -                    Symbol (reserved=15588KB, committed=15588KB)
                               (malloc=13214KB #128579) 
                               (arena=2374KB #1)

   -    Native Memory Tracking (reserved=3220KB, committed=3220KB)
                               (malloc=249KB #3553) 
                               (tracking overhead=2971KB)

   -               Arena Chunk (reserved=178KB, committed=178KB)
                               (malloc=178KB)
   ```
5. Have also checked memory consumption of java process using ps (550m) and htop (res 604m)

**Issue**

The pod has single container and that container has only this java application running with above mentioned configs. This java application essentially downloads images in parallel using threads with some validations like image size, dimension etc. The pod memory consumption keeps increasing until it almost hits that limit and the application restarts. I have read through many different posts and articles and I can't figure out what is causing this memory to keep going up.

Edit 1: Docker image is based off openjdk:8-jdk-slim
Edit2: Some screenshots of monitoring
[image: total container memory usage]
[image: memory snapshot of application in visualvm]
[image: heap usage of application in visualvm]

Comment: Look inside with visualvm

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen visualvm mostly gives data about heap, metaspace etc. , things that we already know from NMT stats. Is there anything I'm missing here or any particular section I should be looking at ?

Comment: It gives you actual numbers on how the JVM looks at the world.    This might be different from what is expected so you may have a spike outgrowing the pod faster than the OOM can trigger.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen  Xmx is 300m and container max is 700m . Even if there is sudden spike in heap usage the total memory consumed by docker container should never reach close to 700 m right ?

Comment: Measure.  See what actually happens - your assumptions may be subtly incorrect.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen : I tracked one of the pods that's been running for 8 hrs, but the requests have started coming in only in the past 4 hrs or so. I'm attaching the visualvm screenshot and memory consumption of container as a whole. I still don't see what is causing this surge.

Comment: Slowly growing heap even with garbage collections _could_ indicate a small memory leak. I would suggest monitoring a load test.

Comment: @vinayhudli did you find the root cause? i am facing the exact same issue. my pod request and limits are 4/6 gb. my total committed native memory reduced from 841mb to 700mb. but my pod memory increased from 900mb to 4GB over time.

Comment: Not directly relevant to your question, but relevant to your workload: https://home.robusta.dev/blog/stop-using-cpu-limits

Answer (score 0):

We had exactly the same problem with Java on GKE, in our case a Spring Boot server running in an Alpine Linux container.  The problem is not in your Java code, it's in the Java VM itself: on Linux, it cannot handle extremely multi-threaded applications which allocate and then deallocate a lot of memory.  Thankfully there's a solution: jemalloc.  Assuming you're using Alpine, simply add the following to your Dockerfile:

```
RUN apk --no-cache add jemalloc
ENV LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libjemalloc.so.2
```

Problem solved.  It took our Spring Boot containers down from 3.5GB to 2.6GB.

If the above is difficult for some reason, try setting MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=4 (or 2).

Answer (score 0):

If this issue is still relevant, there have been many updates to the JDK 8 since the question was posted, so updating the JDK and migrating to a smaller base image should alleviate the situation.

For example, there are two great lightweight Linux distributions, [Alpine](https://www.alpinelinux.org/) and [Alpaquita](https://bell-sw.com/alpaquita-linux/) - both are free and open source. Alpaquita also has a glibc version, so if you have used a glibc-based distro before, migration will be seamless. And it also includes four mallocs: you can choose one best fit to your workloads and improve the performance even more. To my knowledge, Alpine doesn't include additional mallocs.

Of course, the best solution would be to upgrade the Java version, because not all improvements to JVM performance are ported to older releases. But if it is not possible right now, try the recommendations above.